# Set VS Code profile in devcontainer

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

VS Code [recently introduced profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_profiles) that let you define settings and extensions for a workflow.

Is there a way to tell a `devcontainer.json` file to simply use one of these profiles?